# Docker and Puppet

Tags: dns, puppet, docker

I've created a docker container which has puppet installed. I want to kick off a puppet run via `puppet agent -t` where the server has been configured in the `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf` file.

I get this error:

```
dnsdomainname: Name or service not known
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
Exiting; no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled
```

But I do get a valid record returned when I do a `dig` on the puppet master hostname. So I'm not sure why I'm getting that dnsdomainname error. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. I had to put an entry in my /etc/hosts file for the container's IP mapped to localhost.